# How Do I Take Multiple Inputs From the same Input Box and store them?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I am currently taking inputs about a new event and storing them in local storage like this.

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
   Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE="" id="input1"><br />
   Event Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value="" id="input2"><br />
   Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE="" id="input3"><br />
   Event Notes: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE="" id="input4"><br />
   <button onclick="storeValues()" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>

    <script>
   document.getElementById('input1').value = localStorage.getItem("EventName");
   document.getElementById('input2').value = localStorage.getItem("EventDateAndTime");
   document.getElementById('input3').value = localStorage.getItem("EventLocation");
   document.getElementById('input4').value = localStorage.getItem("EventNotes");


function storeValues() {
    localStorage.setItem("EventName", document.getElementById('input1').value);
    localStorage.setItem("EventDateAndTime", document.getElementById('input2').value);
    localStorage.setItem("EventLocation", document.getElementById('input3').value);
    localStorage.setItem("EventNotes", document.getElementById('input4').value);
}
</script>
```

But I am pretty sure whenever I take a second input it overwrites it in local storage. How would I change it so i can take these inputs multiple times?

Comment: Takes inputs multiple times? Would you please clear that statement a bit?

Comment: 1. Ditto @SifatHaque's request for clarification 2. Do these values ever leave local storage? Wondering why you need to store multiple form inputs from one user in local storage without it being saved elsewhere (stored on your server and populated based on cookie id or something similar) - you'll probably need to write a check for local storage/if it exists and create auto incrementing values to append to each name for each record, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: Can't edit, but ignore what I said about auto-incrementing above, as others have shown an array of values is going to be better/cleaner for you long term.

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to both be stored, then you have to name them differently.

What you probably want is something like an array of values in local storage, which if I remember correctly doesn't work out of the box? I don't really remember, but you could probably serialize/unserialize this array data as a JSON string.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to store an array in storage (of course you will have to stringify the array to store as string and later parse it to operate onto it.)

I have written a snippet it will give you an idea.

```html
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
    Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE="" id="input1"><br />
    Event Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value="" id="input2"><br />
    Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE="" id="input3"><br />
    Event Notes: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE="" id="input4"><br />
    <button onclick="storeValues()" type=button>Submit</button>

    <ul id="eventLists">

    </ul>
</form>

<script>

    function loadEvents() {
        let ul = document.getElementById("eventLists");
        ul.innerHTML = "";
        let events = localStorage.getItem("events");
        if (events) {
            try {
                events = JSON.parse(events);
                events.map(e => {
                    ul.innerHTML += `<li>Event named as '${e.name}' dated on '${e.date}' will be held at ${e.location}. (${e.notes})</li>`
                })
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
    }


    loadEvents();

    function storeValues() {
        // getting previous values
        let events = localStorage.getItem("events");


        let newEvent = {
            name: document.getElementById('input1').value,
            date: document.getElementById('input2').value,
            location: document.getElementById('input3').value,
            notes: document.getElementById('input4').value
        }

        try {
            if (events) {
                events = JSON.parse(events);
                events.push(newEvent);
            } else {
                throw Error("no events key here."); // just to take us to the catch block
            }
        } catch (err) {
            events = [newEvent];
        } finally {
            // save into storage
            localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(events));
            loadEvents();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to reuse this form to create multiple events and store those data to your localStorage. If that's the case then you can check my solution.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform" action="" method="GET">
   Event Name: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="name" VALUE="" id="input1"><br />
   Event Date and Time: <INPUT TYPE="datetime-local" NAME="date" Value="" id="input2"><br />
   Event Location: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="location" VALUE="" id="input3"><br />
   Event Notes: <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="notes" VALUE="" id="input4"><br />
   <button onclick="storeValues(event)" type=submit>Submit</button>
</form>

    <script>


function storeValues(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    let storedEvents = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Events")) || [];
  
    const newEventDetails = {
      name: document.getElementById('input1').value,
      dateTime: document.getElementById('input2').value,
      location: document.getElementById('input3').value,
      notes: document.getElementById('input4').value
    }
    storedEvents.push(newEventDetails);
    localStorage.setItem("Events", JSON.stringify(storedEvents));
    
    console.log('storedEvents', storedEvents);
    
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```